# Creating dynamic tags and sending there value in ajax and Validation in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

let me tell you what i am trying to do->

 **Creating 7 checkbox of weekend names then in each of the front of them there is 2 tags(time tag) one is Start and second one is end time. What i am trying to do is making it dynamic like if there is 7 checkbox and i have selected 2 checkbox then only checked Start and end time will pass in ajax. if someone type something in check box and didn't check the checkbox then it should not pass the value of the unchecked checkbox. You can see in the image.you will get the idea.**

Image->[THIS IS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwnXj.jpg)

**Now lets see the code**
Here is the php code but i really do not know what id should i give to get access in jquery. but i want to do dynamic if i add one more checkbox it should automatically do same thing.

```
 <form  id="checking"  method="POST">
        <?php
    $checkbox='';
    $weeknames=array(1=>'Monday',2=>'Tuesday',3=>'Wednesday',4=>'Thursday',5=>'Friday',6=>'Saturday',7=>'Sunday');
    foreach($weeknames as $key=>$value)
    {
        $checkbox.='<br/><input type="checkbox"   name="mycheck" value='.$value.' />'.$value.'&nbsp Start<input type="time" id='.$key.'/>End<input type="time" id='.$key.'  />';
    }    
echo $checkbox.'<br/>';
?>
        <button  id="sub"  name="btnregister">Submit</button>      
        </form>
```

**here is jquery and ajax**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#checking').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
                 var myCheckboxes = []; 
            $.each($("input[name='mycheck']:checked"), function(){            
             myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            });            
            $.ajax({
        url: "functions.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: ,
        async: true,
        contentType:"application/octet-stream" ,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data!=1)
            {
                alert('Done');
               // $("#msg").after('<span class="error">Your Are Registered </span>');
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Not Ok");
            }  
        }
   });

      });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: Is anyone who can tell me

Comment: what error its shows

Comment: remove data attribute

Comment: on your function.php check is it posting data

Comment: remove contentType:"application/octet-stream" ,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

Comment: at the last  return false

Comment: my question is how to get the checkbox checked value and its start and end time

Comment: i want it dynamically to get checked checkbox value and entered start and end values of that checkbox- and send it in ajax -save it in database....I am only getting checked checkbox value not start and end tag values

Comment: ANYONE is here to help